# Array sort by the index variable

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, sorting

I'm having some difficulties sorting a simple array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => EU West (Ireland)
            [1] => eu-west-1
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => South America (Sao paulo)
            [1] => sa-east-1
        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => US East (Virginia)
            [1] => us-east-1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Asia Pasific (Tokyo)
            [1] => ap-northeast-1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => US West (Oregon)
            [1] => us-west-2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => US West (N. California)
            [1] => us-west-1
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Asia Pasific (Singapore)
            [1] => ap-southeast-1
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => Asia Pasific (Sydney)
            [1] => ap-southeast-2
        )

)
```

I want to sort this array on Index. I used `ksort()` but it doesn't work, it leaves an output 1.

Answer (score 6):

[`ksort()`](http://php.net/ksort) doesn't return the sorted array, but rather it sorts the array in place. After calling `ksort($array)`, the contents of `$array` will be sorted. The function returns whether the sort was successful or not.

Example:

```
$array = array(1 => 1, 20 => 1, 5 => 1);

echo "Before ksort():\n";
print_r($array);

if (ksort($array)) {
    echo "ksort() completed successfully.\n";
}

echo "After ksort():\n";
print_r($array);
```

The above prints:

```
Before ksort():
Array
(
    [1] => 1
    [20] => 1
    [5] => 1
)
ksort() completed successfully.
After ksort():
Array
(
    [1] => 1
    [5] => 1
    [20] => 1
)
```

You shouldn't check the return value of `ksort()` though, since `ksort()` can only fail in situations in which it doesn't even get to return a failure. Therefore, the function will either return `true` or the script will die, in which case the return value is irrelevant (it will always be `true`).

Answer (score 1):

Sort uses pass-by-reference for the array, and the return value is a boolean success or failure.
I assume you're doing

```
$myArray = ksort($myArray);
```

change to

```
$sorted = ksort($myArray);
if (!$sorted) {
    echo 'Failed to sort';
}
```

Comment: Could you shrink this down to if(!ksort($myArray)) { //failed } ?

Comment: Most people don't even bother testing the return status at all, I only included it here to demonstrate that the returned value is a success/failure status

Comment: Indeed, also, there's not much you can do if it fails, and the reasons for it failing could be quite obscure... In practice, it really doesn't fail unless some catastrophic problem occurrs, in which case `ksort()` failing will be the least of the problems.

Comment: (actually, looking at source code, I see that `ksort()` will only fail if `pemalloc()` fails or if the parameters to the function are incorrect, and in either case, the script should die before `ksort()` even gets to return)

Answer (score 0):

Use like

```
ksort($array);
```

After that print

```
print_r($array);
```

If you have used

```
print_r(ksort($array));
```

then it will return 1 if array is sorted